# Is there any way in which each do can go to the infinte loop in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am new to ruby, i am trying to create an endless loop in ruby,is there any way to create an endless using each do . I know by using for,while we can achieve it.

Comment: I wanted specifically using each do

Comment: `1.step.each { puts "Take out the trash!" }`

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That loop will, however, not only take infinite time but also allocate infinite memory.

Comment: You could use `loop` as answered below, why insist on using `each`? It would be a misstatement of the method `each`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, `1.step` returns an enumerator, so I don't understand your comment about allocating infinite memory. I tried `1.step.each { |i| puts \`ps -Ao rss=\`.split.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)}`, which reports free system memory in kilobytes. It was not decreasing. (Note I escaped the backticks.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It `yield`s an `Integer` for every iteration, that `Integer` must be allocated in order to `yield` it, even it if it isn't used. With YARV, on a typical 64-bit platform, that `Integer` will first be a `Fixnum` occupying 8 bytes, after ~9 quintillion iterations, it will overflow into a `Bignum` occupying 16 bytes for the payload plus a number of bytes for the object header, after ~170 undectillion iterations, it will add another 8 bytes, after about 6E76 iterations, it will have doubled in size, and so on. Basically, you have a *veeeeeeeery* slow-growing O(log n) memory leak.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, if I had a block variable, each of those integers would become orphaned, and hence a candidate for garbage collection, when the block variable is assigned to the next integer passed to the block. If there is no block variable each of those integers is born an orphan and therefore marked for garbage collection. No? In any event, can you explain why I detected no reduction in free memory after many billions of iterations?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Because billions of iterations are not enough. You need 9 quintillion operations to see an increase of memory by approx. 20 bytes, and another 170E36 iterations to see an increase of memory by another 8 bytes. Assuming that you can run one iteration for every clock cycle of your CPU, it will take you roughly 1 month to see the first increase in memory, and 1 sixtillion years to see the second jump. Like I said, *veeery* slow-growing, but still, *not* an infinite loop, just a very long one. A sufficiently smart compiler might eliminate the allocation, but you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..1.0/0).each do |i|
  your code
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the infinite [`loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop):

```rb
loop do
  my_code
end
```

[`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) is also an option if you want to loop on the same values over and over:

```
["a", "b", "c"].cycle { |x| puts x }  # print, a, b, c, a, b, c,.. forever.
```